# Only grep img tags that contain a keyword, but not img tags that don't?

Tags: regex, grep, bbedit

Using grep/regex, I am trying to pull img tags out of a file. I only want img tags that contain 'photobucket' in the source, and I do not want img tags that do not contain photobucket.

Want:

```
<img src="/photobucket/img21.png">
```

Do Not Want:

```
<img src="/imgs/test.jpg">
<img src="/imgs/thiswillgetpulledtoo.jpg"><p>We like photobucket</p>
```

What I have tried:

```
(<img.*?photobucket.*?>)
```

This did not work, because it pulled the second example in "Do Not Want", as there was a 'photobucket' and then a closing bracket. How can I only check for 'photobucket' up until the first closing bracket, and if photobucket is not contained, ignore it and move on?

'photobucket' may be in different locations within the string.

Comment: try <img src=\"[/a-zA-Z0-9]+photobucket[/a-zA-Z0-9]+\.\w+\">

Comment: i do need the wildcards in there though, as not all of the img tags are consistently "img src=", some contain classes, some contain alt text, some do not.

Comment: true..let me do some thing about it

Comment: now? 

<img.*src=\"[/a-zA-Z0-9_]+photobucket[/a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.\w+\".*>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -o '<img[^>]*src="[^"]*photobucket[^>]*>' infile
```

`-o` returns only the matches. Split up:

```
<img          # Start with <img
[^>]*         # Zero or more of "not >"
src="         # start of src attribute
[^"]*         # Zero or more or "not quotes"
photobucket   # Match photobucket
[^>]*         # Zero or more of "not >"
>             # Closing angle bracket
```

For the input file

```
<img src="/imgs/test.jpg">
<img src="/imgs/thiswillgetpulledtoo.jpg"><p>We like photobucket</p>
<img src="/photobucket/img21.png">
<img alt="photobucket" src="/something/img21.png">
<img alt="something" src="/photobucket/img21.png">
<img src="/photobucket/img21.png" alt="something">
<img src="/something/img21.png" alt="photobucket">
```

this returns

```
$ grep -o '<img[^>]*src="[^"]*photobucket[^>]*>' infile
<img src="/photobucket/img21.png">
<img alt="something" src="/photobucket/img21.png">
<img src="/photobucket/img21.png" alt="something">
```

The non-greedy `.*?` works only with the `-P` option (Perl regexes).

Comment: does [^>]* count as a wildcard, which basically says 0 more of anything but the right bracket?

Comment: Exactly: it's a character class (or "bracket expression") `[]`, with the first character a `^`, which negates the class. It's a way to get a non-greedy match when you know the delimiters.

Comment: I was unaware that you could only put a negate character in and have it match everything else.

Comment: This is the winner. Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Just add a negation of `>` sign:

```
(<img[^>]*?photobucket.*?>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/tZ9lI9/2

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<img[^>]*?photobucket[^>]*?>
```

This way the regex can't got past the '>'

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pattern:

```
<img.*src=\"[/a-zA-Z0-9_]+photobucket[/a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.\w+\".*>
```

I´m not sure the characters admited by the name folders, but you just need add in the ranges "[]" before and after the "photobucket".